# Why keywords in tcl and c pop up when to call tag completion for python?

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, tags, tcl

Evironment:debian8+vim8.
filetype is on status  both in  .vimrc and vim/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim .

```
cat   .vimrc
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

cat vim/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim
setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
filetype plugin indent on
"other lines omitted.
```

Some questions puzzled me.
1.on omni completion
1.1 class name in module
The class or method in a module can be completed.
[image]

1.2 build-in function name

```
import sys
for key,value in enum
```

To press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>,no `enumerate` pop up,
Why build-in function name can't be completed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> ?

2.tag completion
No tag file prepared for python file,no `ctags -R *` executed for any python file.
Where did  vim get these keywords from  when to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> in editing `test.py`?

To input `fil` in test.py and call omni completion with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>,no omni completion menu pop up.
To input `fil` in test.py and call tag completion with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>,tag completion menu pop up.

[image]
For the matched keyword `fileAttrStringsProc`,

```
grep  -lr   'fileAttrStringsProc'  /usr/include/
/usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl-private/generic/tcl.h
/usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl.h
grep  -n  'fileAttrStringsProc'  /usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl.h
1805:    Tcl_FSFileAttrStringsProc *fileAttrStringsProc;
```

For the marched keyowrd `file_handle`,

```
grep  -lr   'file_handle'  /usr/include/
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h

grep  -n  'file_handle'   /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl-linux.h
311:struct file_handle
403:                  struct file_handle *__handle, int *__mnt_id,
410:extern int open_by_handle_at (int __mountdirfd, struct file_handle *__handle,
```

The keyowrd `file_handle` is in a c file.
2.1  tcl keywords pop up
Why  keywords in tcl pop up when to call tag completion for python?

2.2  c keywords pop up
Why  keywords in c file pop up when to call tag completion for python?

3.Which file control the behavior of tag completion?
The file here ,/vim/runtime/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim ,control the behavior of omni completion.
Which file control the behavior of tag completion?
Why no tag file for any python file,to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> output tag completion menu?

Answer (score 9):

Those are not actually Tcl keywords, but rather functions, arguments or methods in Python that bind to Tcl commands. (Tcl wouldn't have the underscores in there.)

The binding from Python to Tcl is part of Tkinter.

Comment: How to explain the keyword `file_handle` then ,it is in c file?

Comment: The `file_handle` stuff is Python-side somewhere (no idea where from). It doesn't correspond to anything meaningful in Tcl (where the equivalent concept is called a “channel”).

Comment: What is the reaction process when to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> for calling tag completion?

Comment: and other questions??